# Where to store custom logs that will be shown to end users?

Tags: 2010, 2013, development, logging, uls

I have a custom job that can process various documents. I'd like to show user-friendly logs of the processing summary on a custom CA application page, e.g.:

```
"[time] Document1.docx from site <url> was processed." 
"[time] Document2.docx from site <url> was skipped." 
...
```

**Is there a better place to store such logs than the ULS log?** The key idea here is that I would like to keep these kind of brief, user-friendly log records separate from the more detailed diagnostic logs (which is what I can put in the ULS log, windows event logs etc.). I'd like logs to be stored per content database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store them in a custom list.